# how to create a random name generator in as3

Tags: mysql, xml, actionscript-3, flash

I'm fairly new to AS3, and i'm creating a kind of basketball game, and i'm trying add random names to each team ( about 12 minimum to 15 maximum to each team). what approach should I use. xml????. etc any advice would help thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep modifying names then use XML, which contains names. Load that xml on game app start and process it.

e.g. The name of your xml is `Teams.xml` and it might look like so,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<teams>
  <name>ABC</name>
  <name>LMN</name>
  <name>EFGH</name>
  <name>And so on</name>
</teams>
```

Then with ActionScript, process that XML and get random name like so,

```
 var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
 xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onXMLLoad);
 xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest("Teams.xml"));

 function onXMLLoad(e:Event):void
 {
      var xml:XML = new XML(e.target.data);
      var totNames:int = xml.children().length();   

      var randomNameIndex:int = int(Math.random() * totNames);  
      trace("Name: " + xml.name[randomNameIndex]);
 }
```

This way you add and/or modify names without compiling SWF.

Answer (score 1):

There's a [`random` function in the `Math`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Math.html#random%28%29) class that you can use to generate a number between 0 and 1.

As for names, you could get a list of names from somewhere, put them into an `Array`, and use `Math.random()` to select names from that list. I actually made a giant list of *surnames* a while back that I was using for allocating random names in an RPG I made. It can still be found [here](https://www.facebook.com/notes/marty-wallace/the-massive-long-list-of-surnames/259911418399) and is already formatted to include quotes and commas, so you can whack it straight into your code like so:

```
var surnames:Array = ["Abraham","Abrahams","Abrams","Acklny","Adams","Agland","Ahearne","Ahern","Akahoshi","Akars","Alchin","Aldridge","Alexander","Algie","Allan","Allard","Allen","Alley","Allport","Allsop","Ambrose","Amor","Anable","Anderson","Andrews","Angel","Ansell","Appleton","Apps","Archer","Armstead","Armstrong","Arnall","Arndt","Arthur","Arthurs","Arundel","Ashcroft","Atkinson","Atwood","Auld","Austin","Avery","Ay","Aylett","Baddeley","Bailey","Baillie","Bain","Baker","Balderstone","Ball","Banks","Baratt","Baret","Barker","Barkle","Barnes","Barnett","Barrett","Barrow","Barry","Bartlett","Barton","Barwick","Basterfield","Bates","Bathgate","Batkin","Batten","Baxter","Beale","Beardsley","Beck","Becker","Beckhouse","Becquet","Bedford","Beech","Beeney","Behrens","Belgrove","Bell","Benn","Bennes","Bennett","Bensley","Benson","Bentley","Bergelin","Berrel","Berrell","Berry","Beven","Beveridge","Biddle","Bill","Bilsborough","Bilton","Binns","Birch","Bircumshaw","Bishop","Bisset","Blackburn","Blackman","Blake","Blakely","Blanksby","Blanton","Blayney","Bleeks","Blewer","Bligh","Bodle","Boet","Bokenham","Bond","Bone","Booker","Bookey","Bool","Booth","Borman","Borrett","Borthwick","Bothersley","Bottomley","Bourke","Bowden","Bower","Bowerman","Bowick","Boyd","Boyle","Boyton","Bradley","Bradney","Bramley","Branson","Bratby","Bray","Brayne","Breeze","Brennan","Brewer","Briant","Bridges","Brien","Bright","Brightwell","Brogan","Broke","Bromage","Bromilow","Brooker","Brookes","Brooks","Brothers","Brouwer","Brown","Browne","Brownlee","Brownlow","Brunet","Bryan","Bryant","Bryce","Buchannan","Buckland","Buckley","Bugden","Bulger","Bulgeries","Bull","Bullen","Bullman","Bunce","Bunn","Bunten","Burch","Burchall","Burgess","Burke","Burnell","Burnett","Burrell","Burslan","Burton","Butchart","Butcher","Butler","Butt","Butterfield","Bye","Byrne","Byrnes","Cade","Cafiero","Cahill","Callaghan","Cameron","Campbell","Candish","Cann","Cardwell","Carmichael","Carn","Carnes","Carney","Carr","Carrington","Carroll","Carruthers","Cartwright","Casburn","Casey","Cassan","Castellano","Catt","Chalker","Chamberlain","Chapman","Chard","Cheesman","Cheney","Chilcott","Childs","Chinnery","Chivers","Choulerton","Chown","Christie","Chubb","Churchill","Chuter","Clarke","Clarkson","Claxton","Clayton","Clemance","Clements","Cleus","Clewett","Clifford","Clissold","Close","Clubb","Clune","Cluskey","Coaker","Coble","Cochrane","Coddington","Cody","Cole","Coleman","Colgan","Colling","Collingwood","Collins","Coloclough","Cometti","Conaughton","Condon","Conlan","Connor","Conroy","Considine","Cook","Cooke","Coombs","Cooper","Corby","Corey","Corkery","Cornwall","Corr","Corrigan","Costello","Cotash","Cottis","Couldthard","Courtion","Cousins","Couzens","Covel","Cowling","Cox","Coxall","Coxon","Coy","Coyle","Crago","Craig","Cramond","Cramp","Crane","Crawford","Crilly","Critchley","Crittenden","Crocker","Croker","Crome","Cross","Crossley","Cruthers","Cullen","Cummings","Cunningham","Currie","Cusack","Dagg","Dalaney","Daley","Dalton","Daniel","Dantoine","Davenport","Davey","Davies","Davis","Davoran","Dawe","Dawson","Day","Deakin","Dean","Dearden","Deblok","Dehnert","Delamere","Delaney","Delap","Dempsey","Denmean","Denning","Dennis","Dewhurst","Dickson","Diehm","Diffey","Dignam","Dillon","Dobb","Docherty","Doherty","Doig","Donald","Donhardt","Donnelly","Dorcas","Doughty","Douglas","Doverty","Dow","Downes","Downey","Doyle","Drain","Drake","Drew","Dromgold","Druett","Druitt","Duck","Duke","Duncan","Dunkley","Dunn","Dunne","Dustan","Dutch","Dwyer","Dyde","Eacott","Eastland","Eastrow","Edmonds","Edmunds","Edwards","Egan","Eggleston","Eldred","Eldridge","Elliott","Ellisdon","Elphick","Elvin","Elvins","Emery","Emmerton","Englefield","English","Erskine","Etherington","Evans","Eves","Eymer","Facer","Fadden","Fairall","Falconer","Fallardeau","Fallon","Fanshawe","Farlow","Farrell","Faulkner","Fearnley","Feenay","Fellows","Feltham","Fennell","Fenton","Fenwick","Ferguson","Ferriday","Few","Field","Fife","Fildes","Findlay","Findley","Finlay","Finzel","Firkin","Fisher","Fitzgerald","Fitzpatrick","Flack","Flanagan","Flanery","Fleming","Fletcher","Flitton","Flodin","Flood","Fogarty","Foley","Foord","Foots","Ford","Forster","Forsyth","Foster","Fowler","Fox","Francis","Franklin","Franks","Fraser","Frazer","Fredericks","Friedrich","Friend","Frost","Fukuda","Fulford","Fulstone","Funnell","Furguson","Furner","Fursman","Gamble","Gannon","Gard","Garnier","Garradd","Garside","Garven","Garvin","Gates","Gavin","Gay","Geard","Geddes","Gee","Geoghegan","George","Gerrard","Geuer","Gibbon","Gibbons","Gibson","Giddings","Gifford","Gilby","Gilfillan","Gill","Gillard","Gillespie","Gillett","Gilroy","Ginn","Glover","Glynn","Gold","Goldie","Goodchild","Goodfellow","Goodsell","Goodwin","Gordon","Gore","Gorman","Gostelow","Gould","Goulding","Graff","Graham","Grange","Granger","Grant","Gray","Grealey","Green","Greenshields","Greer","Gregory","Griffin","Griffith","Grocott","Grocutt","Grundy","Guest","Guil","Gunn","Gunyon","Guthrey","Guthrie","Guymer","Haddon","Hadley","Hadlow","Hagerty","Hailey","Haines","Hall","Hallett","Halloran","Hamilton","Hammett","Hammond","Hancock","Hancox","Hand","Handicott","Hansell","Hansen","Harden","Hardey","Hardie","Harding","Hardy","Harfield","Harker","Harley","Harmsworth","Harris","Harrison","Hart","Hartwig","Harvey","Haslam","Hatter","Haupenthal","Hayden","Haydon","Hayne","Hearn","Hearne","Hedges","Heffernan","Helme","Helyar","Henderson","Hennessy","Henry","Hession","Hetherington","Hewitt","Hewson","Hickey","Hicks","Higham","Hill","Hills","Hilt","Hincksman","Hindle","Hinton","Hoad","Hoare","Hobbs","Hobday","Hochrey","Hockey","Hodge","Hodges","Hodgins","Hodgkinson","Hodgson","Hof","Hogan","Hogbin","Holbrook","Holding","Holland","Holliday","Hollingsworth","Holmes","Homersham","Hone","Hooper","Hope","Hopkins","Horan","Hore","Horne","Horsley","Horton","Hoskin","Hoskins","Howard","Howarth","Howells","Howes","Howse","Hoy","Hudd","Hudson","Huffman","Hughes","Hulbert","Hulks","Hullett","Hulm","Humphries","Hunt","Hunter","Huntington","Hurley","Hurst","Husk","Hutchinson","Hyde","Hyland","Iceley","Ilett","Ingleton","Ings","Ireland","Irwin","Jack","Jackson","James","Jamieson","Jarrett","Jarvis","Jeffcoate","Jeffery","Jeffs","Jenkins","Jennings","Jensen","Jervis","Jessop","Jewell","John","Johnson","Johnston","Jones","Judd","Jude","Jury","Kavanagh","Keat","Keefe","Keeffe","Keenan","Kelleher","Kellond","Kelly","Kennedy","Kenny","Kensit","Kent","Kentwell","Keogh","Kerly","Kerr","Kerridge","Kershaw","Kestle","Kestye","Keys","Kiem","Kiernan","Kilmartin","Kimmage","Kimura","King","Kingdom","Kinlyside","Kinney","Kenner","Kirk","Kirkby","Knight","Knighton","Knouff","Ladyman","Lamb","Lammey","Lancaster","Lane","Lang","Langford","Langham","Langlein","Langridge","Larby","Larcombe","Large","Larkham","Larkin","Larnder","Lasich","Last","Laundess","Laurance","Law","Lawler","Lawrence","Lawton","Layton","Leach","Leadbeater","Lee","Leecount","Lees","Leeson","Legerton","Legget","Leggett","Leggit","Leitch","Leotine","Lester","Lewis","Lewry","Liggins","Lindsay","Lingham","Linklater","Linn","Lister","Litchfield","Little","Lloyd","Loader","Lock","Lockie","Lockley","Lockwood","Lofts","Long","Longbottom","Longobardi","Lovelock","Lovering","Lovett","Lowe","Lucas","Lucy","Luff","Lumley","Lupton","Lye","Lynch","Maber","Maberly","Macaulay","Macauley","Macdonald","Macfarlane","Macginnis","Mackie","Macklan","Macmillan","Macnamara","Magill","Maher","Makinson","Mallon","Maloney","Malton","Mann","Manning","March","Marcham","Marks","Markwick","Marmont","Maroney","Marsh","Marshall","Martin","Masling","Mason","Mathews","Matthews","Mayers","Mayo","Mays","Mcalister","Mcalone","Mcbride","Mccall","Mccann","Mccarroll","Mccarthy","Mccloud","Mcclung","Mccombie","Mccormack","Mccreath","Mcdonald","Mcdonell","Mcdonnell","Mcfadyen","Mcfarlane","Mcfie","Mcfloride","Mcgee","Mcgilrick","Mcgilvray","Mcgrath","Mcgrogan","Mcguigan","Mcguiness","Mcguire","Mcguirk","Mchale","Mchardy","Mchugh","Mcinerney","Mcinnes","Mcintosh","Mcintyre","Mckay","Mckenzie","Mckinnon","Mckinon","Mclaren","Mclaughlin","Mclean","Mclellan","Mcleod","Mcmahon","Mcmanus","Mcmaster","Mcnally","Mcpaul","Mcphee","Mcquirk","Mcroberts","Mcvicar","Meadley","Meadows","Medlin","Meissner","Meldrum","Menchin","Mendham","Menzies","Merriman","Merris","Metcalfe","Meurant","Middleton","Millard","Miller","Milligan","Mills","Milne","Mitchell","Monaghan","Moncrieff","Moneypenny","Monk","Monks","Moody","Mooney","Moore","Moran","Moreau","Morgan","Morley","Morphett","Morrell","Morris","Morrison","Mortar","Mortimer","Morton","Mosley","Moss","Mould","Mowsar","Muffet","Muffett","Muldoon","Muller","Mullins","Mulvay","Munro","Murcutt","Murnane","Murphy","Murray","Myers","Myles","Nader","Nagata","Nash","Naylor","Neale","Nealon","Near","Neely","Neil","Neill","Neille","Neish","Nell","Nelson","Nesbitt","Neve","Neville","Newham","Newland","Newlands","Newton","Nichol","Nicholas","Nicholls","Nichols","Nicholson","Nicol","Nixon","Nolan","Noonan","Norman","Norris","North","Northrope","Norton","Nosworthy","Noyes","Nunn","Nuttall","Nye","O'brien","O'donnell","O'grady","O'keefe","O'mara","O'neal","O'neill","O'reilly","O'shannessy","O'toole","Oakey","Oakman","Oates","Offord","Oliver","Onslow","Orchard","Orroch","Osborn","Osborne","Oshannessy","Ottey","Ovens","Oxley","Paget","Pagett","Painter","Paley","Palmer","Pamplin","Parker","Parkes","Parkin","Parkins","Parson","Parsons","Part","Pascoe","Patterson","Paulett","Paull","Payne","Peake","Pearce","Pearson","Peck","Peckman","Peghan","Pegrem","Peisley","Pendrick","Penny","Perkins","Perry","Peters","Petrie","Pett","Pettit","Petty","Phelps","Phillips","Picker","Pierce","Pike","Pilgrim","Pilon","Pincott","Pittard","Platt","Poile","Pollard","Pollock","Polt","Powell","Power","Pratley","Pretty","Price","Privett","Probert","Proctor","Pryor","Puckett","Pudsley","Pugh","Pullen","Pulley","Queinall","Quilkey","Quill","Quince","Quinn","Quirk","Raison","Ralph","Ranger","Rankin","Rapley","Rassmussen","Ravenscroft","Rawson","Reagan","Rees","Reeves","Reid","Reigles","Renfrew","Reye","Reynolds","Rice","Richards","Richardson","Riddel","Rideout","Ridley","Rigney","Riley","Rimmer","Ritchie","Rix","Rob","Roberts","Robertson","Robinson","Roche","Rogan","Rogers","Rollends","Rope","Roper","Rose","Rosebottom","Rosewarn","Ross","Roughan","Rowe","Rowland","Rowlands","Rowles","Rowsell","Rudman","Rumbal","Rush","Rushforth","Russell","Ryan","Rynehart","Saillard","Salter","Samuels","Sanders","Sartill","Sasse","Saul","Saunders","Saunderson","Saxon","Scanlon","Scannell","Schomberg","Schulz","Scoolin","Scooling","Scott","Scrivener","Seager","Seale","Seaman","Seberry","Seddon","Sellick","Sephton","Seppings","Seymour","Shaddock","Shanahan","Shankland","Sharkey","Sharp","Sharwood","Shaw","Sheather","Sheddon","Sheed","Sheedy","Shelley","Shepherd","Shepherd","Sherd","Sheridan","Sherwood","Shibata","Shiel","Shields","Shiels","Shoemark","Short","Shrimpton","Shurmer","Siddins","Silk","Simmons","Simms","Simpson","Sims","Singyou","Sivyer","Skipper","Slane","Slocombe","Small","Smart","Smith","Snow","Soden","Solly","Soulby","South","Southern","Southgate","Spackman","Spalding","Spanswick","Spare","Spear","Speer","Spencer","Spicer","Spring","Stace","Stacker","Stafford","Stammers","Stamp","Stannard","Stannard","Stanton","Staples","Stapleton","Stark","Stedford","Steed","Stephens","Stephenson","Stevens","Stewart","Stillard","Stockman","Stockton","Stone","Storey","Story","Stout","Strachan","Struckmeier","Strudwick","Stteme","Stuart","Stubbings","Stubbs","Sturgiss","Sullivan","Sumbler","Supple","Surry","Sutherland","Swan","Sweeney","Sweeny","Sweet","Sykes","Symons","Tafy","Talam","Talbot","Tarran","Tate","Tattersol","Taylor","Taylour","Teakel","Teale","Teiffel","Temple","Tetley","Thomas","Thompson","Thorley","Thorn","Thorne","Thoroughgood","Threadgold","Thrupp","Tibbs","Tickner","Tiley","Tindale","Tinsell","Todkill","Tomkins","Toms","Toohey","Toole","Tracey","Tranter","Treacy","Trimmee","Truman","Tuck","Tully","Tuoey","Turner","Tylee","Tyler","Tynan","Tyson","Underwood","Unknown","Uzelac","Vale","Vallance","Vallentine","Vaughan","Veld","Vincent","Voller","Wade","Wainwright","Walcott","Waldock","Wales","Walker","Walkom","Wall","Wallace","Walter","Walton","Warburton","Ward","Wareing","Wares","Warner","Warnock","Warren","Warton","Watkins","Watson","Watts","Way","Weaver","Weavers","Webb","Webster","Weeks","Weidmann","Weir","Welham","Wells","Wesbe","West","Westgarth","Weston","Whately","Wheeler","Whipp","Whitaker","White","Whiteman","Whitfield","Whittaker","Whittington","Whybrow","Wicks","Widdup","Wiebriekt","Wiggins","Wilcox","Wilkie","Wilkinson","Williams","Williamson","Willie","Willis","Wilson","Wiltshire","Winters","Wise","Wiseman","Witmash","Wolstenholme","Wombwell","Wood","Woods","Wooll","Woollett","Woolley","Wootton","Worldon","Worner","Worthy","Wotherspoon","Wright","Writer","Wroughton","Wyatt","Wythes","Yard","Yates","Yeadon","York","Young","Youngson","Zanker"];

var randomSurname:String = surnames[int(Math.random() * surnames.length)];
trace(randomSurname);
```